# Already hold B1, will immigration be a problem with F1?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I have a B1 visa for the USA which I used in Dec-Jan for 2 months. Now I am back in India, I got a university admission last evening and am planning to go to the USA on the F1 visa in Aug. But my brother is graduating in May and I want to attend his graduation ceremony on the B1 visa. Do you think when I go in Aug on the F1 visa, will the immigration office have a problem with me?

Comment: Is it B1 or B1/2?  Note: you can have multiple US visa (different types). B1 and F1 can be a red flags (but this when applying F1).

Comment: Why would they have a problem?!

Comment: I have B1/2, and I heard immigration officers scrutinize you more if you have made multiple entries frequently, hence the question